# Assign relation id to record on create, but not on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I have two models: Page has many Sections. I'm not using nested resources because there's a third model also. In my page#show I have a link to create a new Section belonging to the current Page:

```
<%= link_to 'New Section', new_section_path(:page_id => @page) %>
```

And in my Section view's form I have:

```
<%= form_for(@section) do |f| %>
.
.
.
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<%= f.hidden_field :page_id, :value => params["page_id"] %>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

The problem, of course, is that this passes the page_id into the new Section form correctly, but when the user goes back to the form through the edit path, params["page_id"] is empty. I'd like to set the page_id once on create, and never let it be changed again (perhaps there's a way to create a conditional that removes that hidden field from the form, or an even cleaner way?).

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Wrapping the hidden field tag in <% if params.has_key?(:page_id) %>...<% end %> is working. Is there a better, Railsier way to do this?

Comment: or `params.try(:[], :page_id)`

Comment: no wrapping use inline `<%= f.hidden_field(:page_id, :value => params["page_id"]) if params.has_key?(:page_id)%>`

Comment: The Railsier way would be to use nested resources (e.g. /pages/1/sections/new). What is the difficulty involving your third model? It seems like your current approach allows for a sort of broken workflow when creating sections. What happens when the user goes back to edit and the page_id is not in the params? Do they create an orphaned section? Is this acceptable?

Comment: The issue is that each Section has many Blocks. The Rails guides advise against using nested resources for more than two levels. The broken workflow you're talking about is why I'm asking the question; I'm looking for a way of assigning the page_id only on create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to get the `page_id` from the params, but rather from the resource.  You'd do this by assigning the page id to the new resource in the controller.

In your controller:

```
def new
  # In reality you might create the new Section differently,
  # but you get the idea.
  #
  # In other scenarios the page_id might come from the parent
  # (in a nested route) or some other source not determined by
  # params.
  @section = Section.new(page_id: params[:page_id])
end
```

Then in your template, let the `page_id` populate naturally:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :page_id %>
```

The edit form will already work, as the record already has a `page_id` (as long as all sections have page ids, which I assume they do).

---

Side note: as a general rule, you want to avoid using request params in views, as this is a mix of concerns (controller <-> view) and will lead to fragility & other issues (as you've found).  Rather, let the controller do your resource gathering and assign them to template variables or what have you.

Comment: Thanks so much. The hardest part of learning Rails for me has been trying to figure out these best practices. Can you recommend books or other resources that explain Rails techniques that follow from these principles?

Comment: I'm a bit out of the rails loop, but [the official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are always helpful.  There seems to be some promising info [collated here](http://railsapps.github.io/best-recommended-learning-rails-books-resources.html).  The two E-books under learning rails are written by some of the biggest names (and Rails source contributors) in the community and look very promising.

Comment: Not trying to go too OT here, but I thought the Hartl tutorial was great– what do you think the issues are?

Comment: Haha I removed that because I realized I don't really have any valid reasons.  My only reasoning is that I've seen about 50 SO questions from people running into issues going through it, but in all likelihood the issues are [PEBCAK](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pebcak) and have nothing to do with the tutorial.